# C - MADV_HUGEPAGE Compile Error

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I was trying to compile some C code, which works fine on Linux with just one command.

`./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`

I need this to be compiled for windows, so I installed cygwin and all the dependencies that I could think of, and now I'm getting a compile error. (Error at `make`).

```
-cpu-miner.o `test -f 'cpu-miner.c' || echo './'`cpu-miner.c
cpu-miner.c: In function ‘miner_thread’:
cpu-miner.c:1056:139: error: ‘MAP_HUGETLB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   persistentctx = (struct cryptonight_ctx *)mmap(0, sizeof(struct cryptonight_ctx), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB | MAP_POPULATE, 0, 0);
                                                                                                                                           ^
cpu-miner.c:1056:139: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
cpu-miner.c:1056:153: error: ‘MAP_POPULATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   persistentctx = (struct cryptonight_ctx *)mmap(0, sizeof(struct cryptonight_ctx), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_HUGETLB | MAP_POPULATE, 0, 0);
                                                                                                                                                         ^
cpu-miner.c:1058:88: error: ‘MADV_HUGEPAGE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   madvise(persistentctx, sizeof(struct cryptonight_ctx), MADV_RANDOM | MADV_WILLNEED | MADV_HUGEPAGE);
                                                                                        ^
make[2]: *** [Makefile:563: minerd-cpu-miner.o] Error 1
```

The full code is over here:
https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi

I installed Cygwin with gcc, ming-w64, libcurl, and openssl, as the project dependencies stated, but I'm stumped here.

(I did make changes to the code for optimization, but they're mathematical tweaks and they work fine on Linux, so I don't think that's the problem.)

### Edit 1

It compiles now! I removed the hugepages thing and it compiled - but it's a Linux executable that has a .exe file name. It needs the cygwin dlls to run.

Comment: Looking at the source, it definitely supports Windows. Perhaps the problem is that your Cygwin build is automatically trying to build a Cygwin binary, rather than a real Windows binary. Try to edit the generated `cpuminer-config.h` and undefine `__unix__` and define `_WIN32`.

Comment: I can't find __unix__ in the cpuminer-config.h, but I did make some progress! It compiled (yay!)... but then http://i.imgur.com/NFShvaQ.png it has missing DLLs?

Comment: user4815162342: I added #define `DISABLE_LINUX_HUGEPAGES 1` to the cpuminer-config.h and it compiled, but it needs every dll in the `C:/cygwin64/bin` folder to run. Once it has all that, it thinks it's running in linux and says stuff about how running in root will make it faster. (Which is expected behavior under Linux.)

Comment: Ok now I added CFLAGS="-march=native" to configure and it compiles without any warnings, unlike last time. It still needs those DLLs though, and it thinks it's in Linux.

Comment: That shows that you're still using the wrong build system, the Cygwin GCC instead of the MinGW GCC. Maybe you need to configure it with `./configure CC="path/to/mingw/gcc"`?

Comment: Hmm, when I add CC="path to mingw-64" then ./configure can't find libcurl anymore.

||||||||||

checking for the version of libcurl... 7.49.1
checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2... yes
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2

||||||||||

It works fine when I just do ./configure.

Comment: Well, do you have a MinGW-compiled libcurl? Just `./configure` works because you get the libcurl provided by Cygwin, which you don't want (if you want to avoid depending on Cygwin).

Comment: Yup, got it to compile. Now I have undefined behavior on any PC which can be fixed if I launch it 5 times. Then it starts working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hugepage" feature is specific to Linux, and isn't available in Cygwin.

Comment: He does have Windows binaries available for download (that work), so how is that possible?

Comment: I dont know. Do you know for sure that they're built with Cygwin? `mmap` is not available on Windows; cygwin emulates it.

Comment: I think it's compiled with MinGW, but it's hard to install dependencies with that, and it's basically the same thing, right?

Comment: No. Not at all. You should read about what MinGW is and isn't on their website.

Comment: So then is it possible to compile this with MinGW?